# Moodle advcheckbox for Administrator

Tags: javascript, php, moodle

I added an advcheckbox form in my face-to-face mod_form.php, where I as admin can check the box, thus allowing the student in the sign up page to see some options for hiring a car, which if the checkbox isn't marked by the admin are hidden. 
Here is my code in mod_form.php

```
$mform->addElement('advcheckbox', 'allowcarhire',    get_string('facetoface_allowcarhire', 'facetoface'));
    $mform->setDefault('allowcarhire', 0);
    $mform->setType('allowcarhire', PARAM_BOOL);
```

And here is my code in the user sign up form (signup_form.php), which give us the options in hiring a car:

```
$mform->addElement('advcheckbox', 'carrequired', get_string('facetoface_carrequired', 'facetoface'));
    $mform->setDefault('carrequired', 0);
    $mform->setType('carrequired', PARAM_BOOL);

    $mform->addElement('date_selector', 'checkin', get_string('facetoface_checkin', 'facetoface'));
    $mform->setType('checkin', PARAM_INT);
    $mform->disabledIf('checkin', 'carrequired', 'notchecked');

    $mform->addElement('date_selector', 'checkout', get_string('facetoface_checkout', 'facetoface'));
    $mform->setType('checkout', PARAM_INT);
    $mform->disabledIf('checkout', 'carrequired', 'notchecked');

    $mform->addElement('advcheckbox', 'minivan', get_string('facetoface_minivan', 'facetoface'));
    $mform->setDefault('minivan', 0);
    $mform->setType('minivan', PARAM_BOOL);
```

How to connect them so, that if the first checkbox in mod_form.php is not checked, the user cannot see the car hiring options in his sign up form? Can be made only wiht php or we need javascript also? Everything else in Moodle is unmodified and is clean installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I assume you have already dealt with saving the setting from the mod_form into the database (I assume you've added a new field called 'allowcarhire' to the table mdl_facetoface to hold this setting).

Now you need to pass this value into the form via the 'customdata' form value (look for the $params = compact('s', ...) line, just above $mform = new mod_facetoface_signup_form(null, $params) in mod/facetoface/signup.php).

Once you are within the form, and assuming you've kept the name 'allowcarhire' when adding the setting to the customdata, you should then be able to write:

```
if ($this->_customdata['allowcarhire']) {
    $mform->addElement('advcheckbox', 'carrequired', ...
}
```

Comment: I did as described: allowcarhire is as `<FIELD NAME="allowhotel" TYPE="int" LENGTH="1" NOTNULL="false" DEFAULT="0" SEQUENCE="false"/>` and in signup.php I set `$params = compact('s', 'backtoallsessions', 'manageremail', 'showdiscountcode',
    'hasselfapproval', 'selfapprovaltandc', 'f2fid', 'waitlisteveryone', 'enableattendeenote', 'signupbywaitlist', 'allowcarhire');`

In signup_form created "extended_params" for the other CBs in lib.php,added new table in install.xml

But it comes:
Notice: Undefined index: allowcarhire in **C:\xampp\htdocs\moodle\mod\facetoface\signup_form.php on line 40**

Comment: Have you written something like $allowcarhire = $facetoface->allowcarhire, before trying to use compact to add it into the array? If the variable doesn't exist then compact can't add it.

Comment: Yes it is in signup_form.php as follows: 
`class mod_facetoface_signup_form extends moodleform {
    function definition() {
        global $CFG;

        $mform =& $this->_form;
        $manageremail = $this->_customdata['manageremail'];
        $showdiscountcode = $this->_customdata['showdiscountcode'];
        $enableattendeenote = $this->_customdata['enableattendeenote'];
        $allowcarhire = $this->_customdata['allowcarhire'];` 
or should it be in defined in signup.php before compact?

Comment: Yes. compact takes the list of variables (which must exist already) and creates an array of those values, indexed by the name of the variable. I'd have thought you would get a debugging warning if you used it without defining the variable first (do you have debugging set to developer + display?)